# VSCode Saving causes code to appear on newline and adds double quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-eslint

[image]

When saving, it automatically formats the code to appear on a newline and surrounds it with double quotes. I am not sure what setting on Prettier is causing this, how do I disable this formatting feature?